# Изменение Cookie после вывода (php)

Tags: php, html

Есть файл-контроллер index.php:

```
require ('templates/authorize.php');
require ('lib/out.php');    

if(!empty($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'out') out();     
//если передана переменная action, то разавторизуем пользователя

if(isLogin($link)){                 //если юзер уже авторизован
$UID = $_SESSION['id'];
$admin = isAdmin($UID, $link);  //определяем, админ ли юзер

}else{                              //если была нажата кнопка Вход
if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
    $error = enter($link);   //ф-ия входа на сайт
    if(count($error) == 0){  //если нет ошибок авторизации, то авторизуем юзера
            $UID = $_SESSION['id'];
            $admin = isAdmin($UID, $link); //определяем, админ ли юзер

            if($admin) {
                header('Location: ./templates/admin.php');
                exit();
            }else {
                header('Location: table/index.html');
                exit();
            }
    }else {
        $admin = false;
        echo $error[0];
    }
}
```

}

Есть форма авторизации в файле authorize.php:

```
<?php
    if(empty($UID))
    {
?>
<form method="POST">
    Логин: <input id="login" type="text" name="login"/><br/>
    Пароль: <input id="password" type="password" name="password"><br/>
    <button type="submit" name="enter">Войти</button>
</form>
<a href="../../index.php?action=out">Выход</a>
<?
}
?>
```

И есть файл out.php:

```
<?php
function out() {
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
    unset($_SESSION['id']);     //удаляем переменную сессии
    setCookie('login', '', time()-3600, '/');     //удаляем куку с логином
    setCookie('password', '', time()-3600, '/');  //удаляем куку с паролем
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/index.php');  //редирект на главную страницу
}
```

После ввода юзером логина и пароля они записываются в куки методом
setCookie('login', 'username', time()+1000, '/'), аналогично пассворд, которые при переходе по страницам сайта проверяются и время сессии обновляется. Также нужно удалять куки при разлогинивании:
setCookie('login', '', time()-1000, '/');
Но установка кук получается идёт после вывода формы авторизации (иначе как их получишь для записи в куку?), поэтому setCookie выдает "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by... [5 строка файла с формой]".

При этом при локальной разработке всё работало, проблема появилась при переносе на реальный хостинг.
Каким образом можно это решить?

Comment: ну так ставь куки до вывода формы. посмотреть бы целиком на код

Comment: "При этом при локальной разработке всё работало, проблема появилась при переносе на реальный хостинг. Каким образом можно это решить?" - тут может быть проблема в том, что локальные настройки сервера отличаются от хостинговых и после переноса код начал выбавать другие ошибки до  "Cannot modify header information" что собственно и привело к отправке заголовков. Так же, зачем подключать шаблон до логики?

Comment: @Lexx918 - не понял, то есть установить куки с левыми значениями, а потом вписать в них те что получил из формы? Но это не поможет например при редиректе по кнопке Выход: header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/index.php');

Comment: @Ein, тут точно разница настроек, но так же верно и то, что на хостинге код ведет себя адекватно, т.е. заголовки нельзя писать после вывода. Но что делать то? Вот мне надо затереть куки с логином/паролем методом setCookie (что вызывает ошибки) и перенаправить юзера снова на index.php. Перенаправление я делаю header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/index.php'); - то есть тоже через установку заголовка и это тоже вызывает ошибку

Comment: "Но что делать то?" - что Lexx918, что я сказали одно и то же разными словами. У вас сначала идёт подключение шаблона `require ('templates/authorize.php');`, а потом уже логика. В чём проблема поменять местами? Т.е. если не пришёл `POST` с данными, то просто выводим форму, если пришёл, то ставим заголовки и только после этого начинаем вывод. Так же, есть вероятность того что на локалке просто был отключён вывод ошибок и вы не видели эту проблему

Comment: @Ein - прошу прощения, надо было полнее код приводить. Добавил еще часть.

Comment: @Ein - 
Перенес шаблон ниже, поймал еще кучу разных ошибок, в результате правок кажется всё заработало, но я так и не понял - как???
Каким образом стала работать функция out(), если в ней точно также setCookie() и header('Location'), которые переустанавливают заголовки уже ПОСЛЕ выводов на экран, на что ранее движок ругался? То есть получается что вывод считается только на одной странице, а после перехода заголовки можно снова переустанавливать?

Comment: Если я правильно понял "вывод считается только на одной странице", то да, для каждого http запроса свои заголовки. Более того, когда вы делаете `header('location: some/url')` клиент посылает новый запрос уже по url которая указана в `location`. Если нет понимания что такое http и базового понимания его работы то рекомендую [изучить этот вопрос](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено переносом подключения (require) шаблонов с формами в конец php скриптов, после кода.
Спасибо тов. Ein.